# WordPress - вывести на странице записи название категории этой записи

Tags: wordpress

Есть кастомный тип записей `post_type=product_page`, который в свою очередь состоит в таксономии `taxonomy=product_category`.

Как вывести на странице записи название категории этой записи?

То есть, когда структура **`ПРОГРАММА / КУРСЫ... / запись`** - то на странице записи вывести название категории этой записи **"`КУРСЫ...`"**

upd. нашел решение, может кому-то пригодится:

```
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product_category', ' ',', ')); ?>
```

Comment: оставлю здесь решение, вдруг кому понадобится.

<?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product_category', ' ',', ')); ?>

Comment: Вы можете опубликовать этот комментарий как ответ на собственный вопрос. Только уточните два момента. Я бы сказал, что речь не о *родительской* категории, а о категории самой записи. Родительская - это "Программа" (вы можете отредактировать вопрос, внизу есть кнопка "править"). И замените strip_tags() на esc_html()

Comment: спасибо, поправил.

Comment: Лучше опубликовать решение не в вопросе, а как *ответ* на собственный вопрос. И принять его потом, когда система позволит (через сутки, кажется).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo esc_html(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'product_category', ' ',', ')); ?>
```